# Filter all JTokens by existence of a property using LINQ C#

Tags: c#, json, linq

In the example below, filter the tokens that do not have id property and that have id property into 2 separate lists to finally save them as json strings.

```
 var inventory=  [
    {"id" : 1,
    "name" : "Apple",
    "type" : "fruit"},
    {"id" : 2
    "name" : "Orange",
    "type" : "fruit"},
    {"name" : "Squash",
    "type" : "Vegetable"},
    ]
```

I tried below hoping to get tokens that doesn't contain id but it doesn't work

```
var list = inventory.Where(x => x["id"] == null].ToList();
var obj = new JObject(list);
string str = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, Formatting.Indented);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var json= @" [
    {""id"" : 1,
    ""name"" : ""Apple"",
    ""type"" : ""fruit""},
    {""id"" : 2,
    ""name"" : ""Orange"",
    ""type"" : ""fruit""},
    {""name"" : ""Squash"",
    ""type"" : ""Vegetable""},
    ]";
    
    var inventory= JArray.Parse(json);
    var list = inventory.Where(x => x["id"] == null).ToList();
    string jsonNoId = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
```

jsonNoId

```
[
  {
    "name": "Squash",
    "type": "Vegetable"
  }
]
```

to get  a list with id properties use

```
 var list = inventory.Where(x => x["id"] != null).ToList();
```